# Mono SerialPort with infiniteTimeout on Read

Tags: c#, mono, serial-port

I have a device that responds async, on event that occurs on the device it sends a status over serial to the host.

So as mono does not have DataReceived event implemented i created a thread "PollRun" in which i have:

```
void PollRun(object param)
{
    byte rcvResponse = 0x00;
    _serialPort.ReadTimeout = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.InfiniteTimeout;
    while (true)
    {
       rcvResponse = _serialPort.ReadByte();
       // SOME handle code...
    }
}
```

The poll run works ok until some point... poll run is a separate thread in the application, but what it happens when i run this application after some inactivity time from the user (eg. no key press on the console app in the main thread....) it stops to work, like if the readByte blocks the whole application

Also no ctrl-c signal helps... I have to manually kill the process.

I'm using ubuntu 11.10 with mono 2.10.5

Is there any known issue with using infinite timeout ? What other way would you do this kind of reading where i must wait for event always?

Thank you!

Comment: Make sure you create and open the `SerialPort` on the same thread that is then using it. Also, try using a timeout of 10 seconds and re-poll afterwards. With a real infinite timeout it's hard to quit an application.

Comment: I make the instance the main application, while i need to write to the serial port. Mybe i'm doing it the wrong way i need to be able to write to the serial port while the poll thread is running. I need to send Enable/Disable device, which must be responsive, and it cannot realy wait for the readByte to finish, and as i have disected the mono code, there should not be any problem writing to the serial port while read working. (fullduplex)... Could _serialPort.BytesToRead property be used to check every 100ms and if it is > 0 the lock the _serialPort execute and read?

Comment: It is full duplex (in theory, I haven't used it that way), but it surely doesn't react well when passed between threads. If you need to write data to it from one thread and read on another, then use a queue mechanism to pass data along - don't bounce a `SerialPort` instance between threads!

Comment: If i look at general example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx it uses one thread for Reading and writes in the main thread, that is the same thing i'm doing, just that probably he has a lower timeout on read... Just like the hw is designed you could be reading at the same time you are writing...

Comment: MS implementation is one thing, Mono (sometimes) is another. I'm just writing what I know, based on fixes I did in the Mono serial port implementation.

Comment: Ok based on your expirience if i make it like this because this is something more complex to use somekind of queueing .... I need 2 threads, would it be enough if i instanciate Serialport in main thread use READ thread with BytesToRead property, and use LOCKing so that in no way two threads simultainously uses instance ? would that be ok ?

Comment: It's not something I've done. What I had tested was that if I had two threads reading from the same port (with locks - only one was reading at a time), things broke. The C code in the .so library is simply assuming there's only one thread. This kind of stinks, but so far was enough for anyone using it in production.